# 'path_matrix' must be a lower triangular matrix

Tags: r, matrix, triangular

I am using the Plspm package in R to and have a question regarding the path_matrix. I cannot run the command since my path matrix:

```
leadCI=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
leadI=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
lean=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
tools=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
mngtCI=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
mngtI=c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0)
succCI=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
succI=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)

ss_pathCII=rbind(leadCI,leadI,Lean,tools,mngtCI,mngtI,succCI,succI)
ss_plspm=plspm(DATSUR[-c(1:9),],ss_pathCII,ss_blo4cksCII,ss_modesCII, boot.val=T,br=200,scaling=scale_list)
```

isn't a lower triangular matrix (Error in check_path(path_matrix) :'path_matrix' must be a lower triangular matrix). However, I believe it is--> everything above the diagonal is zero. What can I change in this matrix to make it a lower triangular matrix?

Comment: Where is the matrix?

Comment: Hi Ronak, the matrix is the 8x8 binary matrix (LeadCI---SuccI)

Comment: you already have everything above diagonal as 0 in `ss_pathCII`. You can set it as `ss_pathCII[upper.tri(ss_pathCII)] <- 0`